# HBase rest API not working for getting namespaces

Tags: json, rest, curl, hbase

I have configured HBase-1.1.5 rest service. Below API's are working properly

- /version/cluster
- /status/cluster
- /

But get namespaces and creating new table is not working.

1. List namespace

   ```
   $ curl -vi -X GET \
       -H "Accept: application/json" \
       "http://example.com:8000/namespaces/"
   ```

> **Exception:** HTTP Error 405 - Method not allowed

2. Create or update table schema

   ```
   $ curl -vi -X POST \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"TableSchema": {"name": "users","ColumnSchema": { "name": "cf" }}' \
     "http://example.com:8000/users/schema"
   ```

> **Exception:** Bad request - The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

I am following the below documentation:

- http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_using_rest_endpoints

Why it is not working? Any other example available for HBase rest API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HBase namespaces support not added in 1.1.5 version.

This support available from 1.2.x, 1.3.x and 2.x versions.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14147